# WiFi dropping only on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi

I am having a lot of problems with Wi-fi. The strange thing is that happens only on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 x86_64 (4.15.0-101-generic) computer, all others have Windows and are not affected.

What happens is that after a while browsing, I lose my internet connection, leaving the icon in the upper right corner with the question mark. To "solve" I need to switch from the 2.4G network to the 5G network (and vice versa), but soon afterwards the problem occurs, often in less than 5 minutes.

I've tried several things, but all without success, but I'll leave all of them here:

When viewing the `dmseg -w` command information, I saw that my country code (which is currently Brazil) was apparently changed to IE:

```
[1610.124972] wlp2s0: associated
[1610.125195] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x804c
[1610.125197] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[1610.125200] ath: doing EEPROM country-> regdmn map search
[1610.125202] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3b
[1610.125205] ath: Country alpha2 being used: BR
[1610.125206] ath: Regpair used: 0x3b
[1610.125210] ath: regdomain 0x804c dynamically updated by country IE
[1610.159599] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by ...
```

I tried to change in `/etc/default/crda`, but without success. Afterwards, I tried to disable powersave by changing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to "2", but also without success.

Note: even after the two changes above, the output of `dmseg -w` remains the same, but `iwconfig` really shows that powersave is disabled.

After that, I tried reinstall netwok-manager, use Google Public DNS, but nothing changed.

Here's some outputs:

**iwconfig:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NAME_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.785 GHz  Access Point: ...   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:154   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci | grep -i wireless:**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search spo.virtua.com.br
```